# Setting pointer within a stuct to null

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I would like to set the pointers `*name` and `*age` in Student struct to NULL. Im not sure how this could be done from the main().

```
typedef struct Student Student;
typedef struct Student{
    char *name; 
    int *age;
} Student;
```

I would like to set the pointers mentioned above to NULL in my main.

My declaration of Student in main is:

```
Student Tom;
```

I am not sure how to set tom.name and tom.age pointers to NULL.

Comment: How do you declare `student` in `main()`. Please post the code and if it's not working why isn't it. And if it's working then why are you asking?

Comment: You're too sloppy with your terminology. "In the following struct" is confused. The struct definition defines a *type*, not a value.

Comment: Setting pointers to null is easy: `Tom.name = NULL;`.  Is that all you're asking about?

Comment: @SteveSummit yes that was I was asking about. I was under the impression that you only set to NULL that way when it is just a plain char variable and not a pointer as it is in this case.

Comment: @Brandon: pretty much the other way around; `NULL` is usually only meaningful in a pointer context.  It represents a well-defined "nowhere" (a known *invalid* pointer value that's guaranteed to be unequal to any object or function pointer value).  The `NULL` macro expands to a *null pointer constant*, which is a zero-valued integral expression (either a naked `0`, or an expression like `(void *) 0`, or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for example the following way

```
Student Tom = { NULL, NULL };
```

or

```
Student Tom = { .name = NULL, .age = NULL };
```

or

```
Student Tom;

Tom.name = NULL;
Tom.age = NULL;
```

Comment: Would Tom.name = NULL work even though it is a pointer? I was under the impression that Tom.name would only work if it was just a char variable and not a pointer.

Comment: @Brandon In general you have to allocate memory dynamically which will be pointed to by Tom.name where you are going to write the actual name of the Tom. For example Tom.name = malloc( 4 * sizeof( char ) ); strcpy( Tom.name, "Tom" );

Comment: @Brandon Why wouldn't it work? `int *i; i = NULL;` works. Just don't confuse `Tom.name` (the pointer itself) with `*Tom.name` (the thing it points to) or `(*Tom).name` or `Tom->name` (which you'd use if `Tom` was a pointer, as opposed to `Tom.name` being a pointer).